# I want to update amazon product price using amazon mws api

Tags: amazon-mws

Any one know how to update amazon product price using Amazon MWS api.

i have updated my product via MWS Scratchpad using feed submission, but i dont know how to send XML Feed to Amazon.

Comment: You need to add specifics about what you have done and what you want.  Right now this question seems too general.

Answer (score 6):

Yaa Amazon is really good with their API documentation Lol....
This might help

```
$paths = array(
        get_include_path(),
        realpath(__DIR__ . '/../AmazonAPI/FeedsAPI/src/'),
    );
    set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths));
    unset($paths);

    //Includes appropriate config data for Amazon API credentials depending on POS associated with the product
    $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = $pos_data['azn_access_key'];
    $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = $pos_data['azn_secret_access_key'];
    $APPLICATION_NAME = $pos_data['azn_app_name'];
    $APPLICATION_VERSION = $pos_data['azn_app_version'];
    $MERCHANT_ID = $pos_data['azn_merchant_id'];
    $MARKETPLACE_ID = $pos_data['azn_marketplace_id'];
    $MERCHANT_TOKEN = $pos_data['azn_merchant_token'];
    $Service_url = $pos_data['azn_service_url'];
    $currency = $pos_data['currency'];

    $merchant_token = $MERCHANT_TOKEN;
    $config = array(
        'ServiceURL' => $Service_url,
        'ProxyHost' => null,
        'ProxyPort' => -1,
        'MaxErrorRetry' => 3);

    $service = new MarketplaceWebService_Client($AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, $config, $APPLICATION_NAME, $APPLICATION_VERSION);

    $feed = <<< EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>$merchant_token</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Price</MessageType>
<Message>
  <MessageID>1</MessageID>
  <Price>
    <SKU>$sku</SKU>
    <StandardPrice currency="$currency">$new_price</StandardPrice>
  </Price>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
EOD;

    echo "\nProduct Price Change Feed for FeedsAPI: \n$feed\n";
    $marketplaceIdArray = array("Id" => array($MARKETPLACE_ID));

    $feedHandle = @fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');
    fwrite($feedHandle, $feed);
    rewind($feedHandle);
    $parameters = array(
        'Merchant' => $MERCHANT_ID,
        'MarketplaceIdList' => $marketplaceIdArray,
        'FeedType' => '_POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_',
        'FeedContent' => $feedHandle,
        'PurgeAndReplace' => false, //Leave this PurgeAndReplace to false so that it want replace whole product in amazon inventory
        'ContentMd5' => base64_encode(md5(stream_get_contents($feedHandle), true))
    );
    rewind($feedHandle);

    $request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_SubmitFeedRequest($parameters);
    $return_feed = invokeSubmitFeed($service, $request);

    function invokeSubmitFeed(MarketplaceWebService_Interface $service, $request)
    {
        $DATE_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d';
        try
        {
            $response = $service->submitFeed($request);
            echo "\n=============================================================================";
            echo "\nSubmitFeedResponse\n";

            if($response->isSetSubmitFeedResult())
            {
                $submitFeedResult = $response->getSubmitFeedResult();
                if($submitFeedResult->isSetFeedSubmissionInfo())
                {
                    $feedSubmissionInfo = $submitFeedResult->getFeedSubmissionInfo();
                    if($feedSubmissionInfo->isSetFeedSubmissionId())
                    {
                        echo "FeedSubmissionId: " . $feedSubmissionInfo->getFeedSubmissionId() . "\n";
                    }
                    if($feedSubmissionInfo->isSetFeedType())
                    {
                        echo "FeedType: " . $feedSubmissionInfo->getFeedType() . "\n";
                    }
                    if($feedSubmissionInfo->isSetSubmittedDate())
                    {
                        echo "SubmittedDate: " . $feedSubmissionInfo->getSubmittedDate()->format($DATE_FORMAT) . "\n";
                    }
                }
                echo "=============================================================================\n";
            }
            if($feedSubmissionInfo->getFeedProcessingStatus() == "_SUBMITTED_")
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
        catch(MarketplaceWebService_Exception $ex)
        {
            echo "Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n";
            echo "Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n";
            if($ex->getStatusCode() == 503)
            {
                echo "\n===> WARNING: AMAZON MWS API REQUEST HAS BEEN THROTTLED <===.\n";
            }
            echo "Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n";
            echo "Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n";
            echo "Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n";
            echo "XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would appreciate if you could approve my answer and rate it please thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Feeds API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/190-9453901-7569555?ie=UTF8&group=bde&section=feeds&version=latest) and if you download one of the client libraries, most of the work is done for you.   They currently offer PHP, C#, and Java.  Plug in your credentials and then modify the sample code for your use case.